# Improve Pandas dataframe filtering speed

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have a dataset with 19 columns and about 250k rows. I have worked with bigger datasets, but this time, Pandas decided to play with my nerves.

I tried to split the original dataset into 3 sub-dataframes based on some simple rules. However, it takes a long time to execute the code. About 15-20 seconds just for the filtering.

Any alternative way that will improve the performance of the code?

```
import pandas as pd

#read dataset
df = pd.read_csv('myData.csv')

#create a dataframe with col1 10 and col2 <= 15
df1 = df[(df.col1 == 10) & (df.col2 <= 15)]
df = df[~df.isin(df1)].dropna()

#create a dataframe with col3 7 and col4 >= 4
df2 = df[(df.col3 == 7) & (df.col4 >= 4)]
df = df[~df.isin(df2)].dropna()
```

In the end, I have the `df1, df2, df` dataframes with the filtered data.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The concept to understand is that the conditional is actually a vector.  So, you can simply define the conditions, and then combine them logically, like:

```
condition1 = (df.col1 == 10) & (df.col2 <= 15)
condition2 = (df.col3 == 7) & (df.col4 >= 4)

# at this point, condition1 and condition2 are vectors of bools

df1 = df[condition1]
df2 = df[condition2 & ~condition1]
df = df[~ (condition1 | condition2)]
```

This will be considerable faster as it only evaluates the conditional once.  Then it uses them to perform indexed lookup to create the new smaller dataframes.

Comment: In case of presence of None or NaN, just beware that boolean logic may not work on them.

Answer (score 6):

Have you timed which line of your code is most time consuming? I suspect that the line `df = df[~df.isin(df1)].dropna()` would take a long time. Would it be faster if you simply use the negation of the condition you applied to obtain `df1`, when you want to filter away rows in `df1` from `df`?

That is, use `df = df[(df.col1 != 10) | (df.col2 > 15)]`.

Comment: +1 for recommending timing each line

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestions in the other answers, it helps if we add the search fields to the DataFrame index. Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Pandas DataFrames support multi-index as well. Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html

An example can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58061800/2130670